# Get Battery Charge Information Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode6, osx-yosemite

(Xcode 6, OSX 10.10.3)
How do I get the battery charge information of a Mac (Charge Status, Battery level, Cycle count, Maximum charge in mAH) programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this'll help you:

1. It uses non-approved calls, so don’t post your application with this code or you may be rejected!

   http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/
2. From Apple; so don't worry about this code:
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html (With complete sample code)

Answer (score 0):

Use `PFSystemKit`. It is a framework that gives you about anything (besides sensors/smc info), including battery life, cycle, temperature and other stuff, just import the framework. Then add `#import <PFSystemKit/PFSystemKit.h>`. Then just add this code for battery info, make sure to change "cycleCount" to something else in a different case

```
 PFSystemKit *systemKit = [PFSystemKit investigate];
 NSString *batteryCycle = [systemKit.batteryReport cycleCount];
 [label setStringValue:batteryCycle];
```

https://github.com/perfaram/PFSystemKit

PS, sorry for a late response :P, and just a heads up I have a macmini so my output is `NULL`!

Comment: The question is for macOS, but both of these solutions are for iOS.