# Using IOKit in macOS app

Tags: macos, iokit

I found several topics where arises the same question, but they're pretty old and most of them don't have a definite answer, or the answer is applicable to iOS only. Also some sources say it's prohibited while other disagree.

For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179473/get-battery-charge-information-programmatically) or [here about iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024247/getting-battery-health-information-on-ios).

I'm interested whether IOKit can be used for **macOS** applications - note! **macOS**, not iOS - to get **only battery information**.

If no, I'd like to find out, how apps like Battery Health work.

What are your guesses? Thanks.

Comment: The documentation of [IOKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit) states that it is available on MacOS 10.0+ Where the method they you wamt to use is available you can check yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IOKit.framework is a reasonably well documented, public API on macOS. Many apps and most 3rd party device drivers use it. For the Mac App Store, entitlements restrictions apply.

Regarding Mac battery status, you probably want to take a look at the `IOPMPowerSource`/`AppleSmartBattery` objects. The output from running the following command on the Terminal should give you an idea of what information is available:

```
ioreg -w 0 -irc IOPMPowerSource
```

The [`AppleSmartBattery` source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-703.1.5/AppleSmartBatteryManager/AppleSmartBattery.cpp.auto.html) is available, that's probably your best reference.